# Elasticsearch Pod failing after Init state without logs

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm trying to get an Elasticsearch StatefulSet to work on AKS but the pods fail and are terminated before I'm able to see any logs. Is there a way to see the logs after the Pods are terminated?

This is the sample YAML file I'm running with `kubectl apply -f es-statefulset.yaml`:

```
# RBAC authn and authz
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - "services"
  - "namespaces"
  - "endpoints"
  verbs:
  - "get"
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: kube-system
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  apiGroup: ""
---
# Elasticsearch deployment itself
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-logging
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
    version: v6.4.1
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch-logging
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
      version: v6.4.1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: elasticsearch-logging
        version: v6.4.1
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: elasticsearch-logging
      containers:
      - image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.1
        name: elasticsearch-logging
        resources:
          # need more cpu upon initialization, therefore burstable class
          limits:
            cpu: "1000m"
            memory: "2048Mi"
          requests:
            cpu: "100m"
            memory: "1024Mi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: db
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: elasticsearch-logging
          mountPath: /data
        env:
        - name: "NAMESPACE"
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: "bootstrap.memory_lock"
          value: "true"
        - name: "ES_JAVA_OPTS"
          value: "-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m"
        - name: "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts"
          value: "elasticsearch-logging"
      # A) This volume mount (emptyDir) can be set whenever not working with a
      # cloud provider. There will be no persistence. If you want to avoid
      # data wipeout when the pod is recreated make sure to have a
      # "volumeClaimTemplates" in the bottom.
      # volumes:
      # - name: elasticsearch-logging
      #   emptyDir: {}
      #
      # Elasticsearch requires vm.max_map_count to be at least 262144.
      # If your OS already sets up this number to a higher value, feel free
      # to remove this init container.
      initContainers:
      - image: alpine:3.6
        command: ["/sbin/sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        name: elasticsearch-logging-init
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
  # B) This will request storage on Azure (configure other clouds if necessary)
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-logging
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        storageClassName: default
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 64Gi
```

When I "follow" the pods creating looks like this:

[image]

I tried to get the logs from the terminated instance by doing `logs -n kube-system elasticsearch-logging-0 -p` and noting.

I'm trying to build on top of [this sample from the official 
(unmaintained) k8s repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch/es-statefulset.yaml). Which worked at first, but after I tried updating the deployment I had it just completely failed and I haven't been able to get it back up. I'm using the trial version of Azure AKS

I appreciate any suggestions

### EDIT 1:

The result of `kubectl describe statefulset elasticsearch-logging -n kube-system` is the following (with an almost identical Init-Terminated pod flow):

```
Name:               elasticsearch-logging
Namespace:          kube-system
CreationTimestamp:  Mon, 24 Sep 2018 10:09:07 -0600
Selector:           k8s-app=elasticsearch-logging,version=v6.4.1
Labels:             addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=Reconcile
                    k8s-app=elasticsearch-logging
                    kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true
                    version=v6.4.1
Annotations:        kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"StatefulSet","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode":"Reconcile","k8s-app":"elasticsea...
Replicas:           0 desired | 1 total
Update Strategy:    RollingUpdate
Pods Status:        0 Running / 1 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:           k8s-app=elasticsearch-logging
                    kubernetes.io/cluster-service=true
                    version=v6.4.1
  Service Account:  elasticsearch-logging
  Init Containers:
   elasticsearch-logging-init:
    Image:      alpine:3.6
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Command:
      /sbin/sysctl
      -w
      vm.max_map_count=262144
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Containers:
   elasticsearch-logging:
    Image:       docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.4.1
    Ports:       9200/TCP, 9300/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Limits:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  2Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  1Gi
    Environment:
      NAMESPACE:                          (v1:metadata.namespace)
      bootstrap.memory_lock:             true
      ES_JAVA_OPTS:                      -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m
      discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts:  elasticsearch-logging
    Mounts:
      /data from elasticsearch-logging (rw)
  Volumes:  <none>
Volume Claims:
  Name:          elasticsearch-logging
  StorageClass:  default
  Labels:        <none>
  Annotations:   <none>
  Capacity:      64Gi
  Access Modes:  [ReadWriteMany]
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From                    Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----                    -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  53s   statefulset-controller  create Pod elasticsearch-logging-0 in StatefulSet elasticsearch-logging successful
  Normal  SuccessfulDelete  1s    statefulset-controller  delete Pod elasticsearch-logging-0 in StatefulSet elasticsearch-logging successful
```

The flow remains the same:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that the pods are terminated due to an ES related error.
I'm not so sure ES even got to run to begin with, which should explain the lack of logs.

Having multiple pods with the same name is extremely suspicious, especially in a StatefulSet, so something's wrong there.
I'd try `kubectl describe statefulset elasticsearch-logging -n kube-system` first, that should explain what's going on -- probably some issue mounting the volumes *prior* to running ES.

I'm also pretty sure you want to change `ReadWriteOnce` to `ReadWriteMany`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There's a way. You can ssh into the machine running your pods, and assuming you are using Docker you can run:

```
docker ps -a # Shows all the Exited containers (some of those, part of your pod)
```

Then:

```
docker logs <container-id-of-your-exited-elasticsearch-container>
```

This also works if you are using [CRIO](http://cri-o.io/) or [Containerd](https://containerd.io/) and it would be something like

```
crictl logs <container-id>
```